# Can I determine memory consumption allocation with XCode's Debugging

Tags: c++, xcode

I have a program on XCode's written with C++.

Some builds my memory consumption skyrockets out of nowhere, while other builds the memory stays constant and works as expected.

Are there any built in debugging features with XCodes that will allow me to view memory consumption on a per variable or per object basis?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score -1):

You should first look into using [Instruments](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/InstrumentsUserGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html) ([wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instruments_(application))). You can run Instruments in Xcode using <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd>. It is built on top of [DTrace](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DTrace).

**DTrace background**

Why is that important?  DTrace lets you ask really interesting, specific questions about the runtime behaviors of your application, whether during debugging or in production.

The beauty of DTrace is in the providers, as well as the scripts (written in the D scripting language - not the same thing as [dlang](http://dlang.org/)). Many languages have DTrace providers that allow you to probe into their standard libraries. There is also a syscall provider that lets you see when applications are hitting lower level system calls. Some third party applications have their own application-specific DTrace providers, often along with handy scripts you can use. Or you can create your own (see below).

**Objc/C++ refresher**

Keep in mind that both Objective-C and C++ essentially coexist with and extend C.  So your `new` and `delete` in C++ are really just `malloc` and `free` with some size calculations done for you based on the class you're working with.  In Objective-C, it's more or less the same story under the hood - things must be `malloc`'d onto the heap.   So whether you're writing C, C++, or Objective-C code (or even Swift code!) there is some common ground we can rely on.

**Instruments**

Getting back to the issue at hand, Instruments simplifies using DTrace by offering a GUI with shortcuts to handy, pre-made scripts. You don't even have to see the scripts. For example, you can launch Instruments and tell it to monitor memory allocations or leaks, and suddenly you get a rolling graph of memory usage in your application.

Once you launch Instruments and start recording a session with the Memory Allocation tool, you should be looking at the "persistent bytes" column (used to be "live bytes"). This is a good starting point. This number will increase and decrease. You'll typically see a net increase over time, but you should see it decrease whenever you're expecting a deallocation to occur - the larger the deallocation, the easier it is to notice. If you are not seeing decreases at those moments, then you'll want to explore your code for bad memory management.

**Taking It Further**

You can even create [custom probes](https://www.bignerdranch.com/blog/hooked-on-dtrace-part-4/).

Here's another in-depth article that describes what you're talking about, with [tracking malloc/free usage from specific lines of your code](https://www.joyent.com/blog/bruning-questions-debugging).

Comment: the question is asking specifically whether there is a way to track allocations within xcode on a per object or variable basis - I don't think this answer really answers that question